# Failure: ocamlfind not found on path, but -no-ocamlfind not used (zsh terminal)

Tags: emacs, ocaml

When I try to compile, in emacs, my file with

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind main.native
```

I have this error :

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind main.native
Failure: ocamlfind not found on path, but -no-ocamlfind not used.
```

When I compile it with the same command but in my terminal (zsh), I have no problem. I think there's a problem with emacs not finding `ocamlfind` but I don't understand what this problem may be. (Everything is installed with opam, I have OCamlbuild and OCamlfind in my installed packages, I did `eval $(opam config env)`)

When I do `M-x getenv PATH` I have exactly the same PATH I have in my terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What made it work is writing this in emacs :

```
(setq shell-file-name "zsh")
(setq shell-command-switch "-ic")
```

And I have no idea why.

Comment: well, you didn't tell that you're using zsh ;)

Comment: Ah crap, does it change something?

Comment: It does, since you're starting emacs from zsh and emacs uses bash, variables are not propagated.  So, did you try the `opam-env` recipe (without setting `shell-file-name` and `shell-command-switch` variables)? It should work.

Comment: As I said, your alternative solution didn't work when I tried it :-(

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the environment is not set up correctly in Emacs. You can run emacs from a terminal in which you did `eval $(opam config env)`, then it will inherit all the needed variables. Alternatively, you can use the following command:

```
(defun opam-env ()
  (interactive nil)
  (dolist (var
           (car (read-from-string
                 (shell-command-to-string "opam config env --sexp"))))
    (setenv (car var) (cadr var))))
```

Just add it to your init scripts, and run with `M-x opam-env`, whenever you run a fresh copy of Emacs, or whenever you switch to another compiler.

Comment: But I am runing emacs from the terminal in which I did `eval $(opam config env)`. I just switched to another compiler and switched back to the previous one and it doesn't work. I tried puting `(setq shell-file-name "zsh")` and it still doesn't work. And neither does your alternative solution, sadly.